# When a page on my site times out, the URL in the address bar exposes the server IP. How do I prevent this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server

On my website, if one of the pages takes too long to load and times out, the address bar changes from the site's domain name to the server's IP address. The webserver used is apache2 with php on ubuntu 18.04. How do I prevent it from doing this?

Comment: It might be more likely to find an answer on StackExchange Web Appplications, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you describe your apache configuration.  Are you using virtualhosts? If so, can you provide your virtualhost configuration.

Comment: @IyadK I didn't change anything from the default config

Comment: are you placing your files in /var/www/ ?  Is this private hosting or shared hosting?

Comment: /var/www/html, this is a private setup using apache2 on ubuntu.